# Import mixed data (string and array of strings) with hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I am trying to import with hive some data of this type:

> 2015-0-6,value1
>
> 2015-0-9,value1,value2,value3

I tried in those ways

```
CREATE TABLE fields (timestamp STRING, fields_array ARRAY<STRING>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

CREATE TABLE fields (timestamp STRING, fields_string STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

but only timestamp and first value are stored in the table.
Eg.:

> 2015-0-6  value1
>
> 2015-0-9  value1

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a python script such as this:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    splitLine=line.strip().split(',', 1)
    print "%s\t%s" % (splitLine[0], splitLine[1])
```

And in your hql type

> CREATE TABLE fields (timestamp STRING, fields_string STRING) ROW FORMAT
>     DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
>
> ADD FILE /your_script_path/script.py;
>
> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE fields SELECT TRANSFORM(line) USING 'python
>   script.py' AS timestamp, fields FROM your_table_in_which_you_have_one_column_called_LINE ;

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SerDe explained in this blog. I think its close to what your requirement is.
https://bigdatamusings.wordpress.com/2014/08/